# How can I send email from my website on ubuntu server

Tags: email

I am using ubuntu 12.04 and I have installed Appache , php , and mysql all the latest versions. I have my website on the root folder of this machine.
Now, I want an email be sent to my boss when ever some one downloads a document from the website after filling the form. I already have designed a form and made all the neccessary validations as well. But I do not know how to send those form contents to my boss in her email address!!

I love ubuntu and am Enjoying it and am a beginner!
would any one please help me??
Thank you so much! 
Joye

Comment: Is this a question about the server setup or a PHP question asking how to send form contents via email? Or both?

Comment: Do you have SMTP installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with installing a MTA. This lets PHP send the email from the server.

```
sudo apt-get install postfix
```

Then in PHP it's fairly simple. Use the [`mail` command](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php):

```
mail('address@example.com', 'Form submission', $_POST['message']);
```

That assumes there was a form element with the name `message` in the form. It also assumes your form is (as it should be) `<form method="post" ...>`.

Comment: A good friend of mine told me to install sendmail for this problem as a solution and I did. I also configured the [mail function] and I tried to send emails...the message from the php code I wrote told me that the email has been send successfully but, there is nothing received when i go and check my emails. I also tried to look at some solved problems ... but I am confused identifying between localhost and localdomain ... I came accros an advise that suggests to edit /etc/hosts file.. my virtual computer name is ABC-HR-System, my hostname (by the result of the command hostname is)xyz. hlp, pls